# Update SQL Data Mismatch In Criteria Error

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

First of all I'm using MS Access OleDb and I tried many times with and without parameters for `UPDATE` SQL query.

Photo update thing not the fact for now, when I try to update button I get:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

and that error drives me crazy, please help me. Thank you!

`ktN` comes from `KayitNo` as `Public Int32` from header and when I clicked to datagrid for update (in that time retrieves other columns to textboxes and datetimePickers etc.)

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=TSP.accdb");
OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE TSP_Data SET SeriNo=@SeriNo,PartNo=@PartNo,PID=@PID,Model=@Model,UretimTarihi=@UretimTarihi,Teknisyen=@Teknisyen,ServisGiris=@ServisGiris,Ariza=@Ariza,TeknisyenNotu=@TeknisyenNotu,YapilanIslem=@YapilanIslem,MudahaleSonucu=@MudahaleSonucu,BoardUzerindekiYeri=@BoardUzerindekiYeri,TamirSeviyesi=@TamirSeviyesi,SonKontrolSonucu=@SonKontrolSonucu,TeslimEdilenTarih=@TeslimEdilenTarih,UrunDurumu=@UrunDurumu Where KayitNo="+ktN,con);

komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeriNo",Convert.ToString(sNText.Text));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNo", Convert.ToString(partNoText.Text));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID",pidText.Text);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model",Convert.ToString(modelText.Text));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UretimTarihi",uretimTarihi.Value);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teknisyen", Convert.ToString(teknisyenSec.SelectedItem));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServisGiris", serviseGirisTarihi.Value);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ariza", Convert.ToString(arizaText.Text));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeknisyenNotu", Convert.ToString(teknisyenNotuText.Text));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YapilanIslem", Convert.ToString(yapilanIslemText.Text));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MudahaleSonucu", Convert.ToString(mudahaleSonucuSec.SelectedItem));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BoardUzerindekiYeri", Convert.ToString(boardYeriText.Text));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TamirSeviyesi", Convert.ToString(tamirSeviyesiSec.SelectedItem));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CaseID", caseIDText.Text);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SonKontrolSonucu", Convert.ToString(sonKontrolSonucuSec.SelectedItem));
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeslimEdilenTarih", teslimEdilenTarih.Value);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UrunDurumu", Convert.ToString(urunDurumuSec.SelectedItem));
```

// komut.Parameters.Add("@Foto", OleDbType.Binary, foto.Length).Value = foto;
    con.Open();
    komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Successful");

The Table Design in order like this:

```
KayitNo(Int,PK,AutomaticNumber)
SeriNo(Long Text)
PartNo(Long Text)
PID(Int)
Model(Long Text)
UretimTarihi(Date/Time)
Teknisyen(Text)
ServisGiris(Date/Time)
Ariza(Long Text)
TeknisyenNotu(Long Text)
YapilanIslem(Long Text)
MudahaleSonucu(Long Text)
BoardUzerindekiYeri(Long Text)
TamirSeviyesi(Long Text)
CaseID (Int)
SonKontrolSonucu(Text)
TeslimEdilenTarih(Date/Time)
UrunDurumu(LongText)
Foto(OLE OBJECT)
```

Comment: why do you randomly not use a parameter for ktN when you do for all other variables? You should parameterise all your input values. As for the error, any of your variables could be being entered incorrectly, but most likely it's the integer or date ones. Check that what's being entered is valid. If it's not - why not? Your app should be validating the entries. In particular if you have dates, make them into DateTime objects not just strings.

Comment: Try Convert.ToDateTime
'komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServisGiris", Convert.ToDateTime(serviseGirisTarihi.Value));'

Comment: @ChrisCatignani i did and nothing changed.

Comment: CaseID is an int and your not converting it either.

Comment: @ADyson you saved my program sir! i just tried one by one and i found the error. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

DateTime values need to be converted from `string` to `sql datetime`

Try: `OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE TSP_Data SET UretimTarihi= convert(varchar(50),@UretimTarihi,101) Where KayitNo="+ktN, con);`

With: `komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UretimTarihi",uretimTarihi.Value.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss"));`

Or with `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss' 'zzz")`

> Have your tried entering the values one by one, to determine which one is giving the errors? Not sure if there's multiple problems, with your insert string. But for certain i've encountered datetime errors when inserting values.